# Medical device on patient's bed..Cannot earth the Chassis..How to provide ESD protection?

Tags: emc, esd, compliance, medical

We are developing a medical device, which will sit on patient's bed. So, the medical device chassis can't be connected to earth. The powersupply of the device is isolated (2MOPP and 2 MOOP), medical grade powersupply (110V primary, 36V secondary..Primary and secondary are isolated 2MOPP)

Now the question is, It has to pass ESD testing (15KV Air, and 8KV contact)..Since the chassis can't be connected to PE (Protective Earth), how can I discharge the ESD energy applied on the metal portion of the chassis (Chassis gnd)..Can I add a ESD diode between chassis gnd to powersupply gnd in secondary?..how the ESD energy will be discharged, if the secondary gnd is isolated..should I add a Y cap? Kindly suggest.

Comment: Well, if you don't achieve a discharge that isn't your device's problem. It just means that it won't be susceptible to ESD.

Comment: It depends on the electrical requirements for a medical device. For example, would a 22 MΩ from mains ground to part of the circuit by patient be permissible? Perhaps a few 22 MΩ resistors in series, to meet 15 kV requirement?

Comment: Do you need to discharge the ESD energy, or is the requirement only that device continues to function when the ESD is applied?